# python: нужен бесконечный цикл по команде

Tags: python-3.x, telebot

у меня есть код:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
elif message.text == 'Бизнес запуск':
    if os.path.isfile(f"C://tgplay/{message.chat.id}_business2.py"):
                file = open(f'C://tgplay/{message.chat.id}_business2.py', 'r+')
                s = file.read()
                number = int(s)
                while True:
                    file.seek(0)
                    file.write(str(number + 2000))
                    sleep(10)
                    file.seek(0)
                    file.close
```

Он после ввода команды добавляет один раз, а нужно бесконечно раз, чтобы в файл пополнялось по 2000 после 10 сек(sleep(10)) без повторного ввода команды, как это воплотить? Я новичок, прошу помощи!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте закрывать файл вне цикла (хотя это не будет иметь смысла, т.к. цикл бесконечный) => просто **удалите строку file.close()**

А еще лучше не использовать бесконечные циклы, особенно с синхронной библиотекой.